# PYQT: Can't reach DOM when using evaluatejavascript in a QThread

Tags: webkit, pyqt, qthread

I run an html file using pyqt/webkit. 
I manage to play with the dom in the onload callback using evaluateJavascript.
unfortunately, If I try to do it elsewhere (inside a Qthread). I'm not able to play with the DOM. note that evaluate javascript is working fine (I can do alert for instance)

The code is as below:

index.html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
 </head>
  <body>
      <div id="info">test</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and the python file:

```
import sys
import time
import PyQt4
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPalette, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsProxyWidget, QGraphicsView, QPainter
from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebSettings
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

global frame



class testQthread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)


    def run(self):
        global frame
        print "****************** IN THREAD 1******************"
        time.sleep(2)   
        print frame
        frame.evaluateJavaScript(' document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="should work here";')
        while True:
           time.sleep(1)



class WithConsole(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, msg, line, source):
        print '%s line %d: %s' % (source, line, msg)


class  HTMLApplication(object):

    def show(self):
        #It is IMPERATIVE that all forward slashes are scrubbed out, otherwise QTWebKit seems to be
        # easily confused

        #This is basically a browser instance
        self.web = QWebView()
        self.web.setAttribute(Qt.WA_X11NetWmWindowTypeDesktop)
        self.web.setAttribute(Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent, True)
        self.settings=self.web.settings()
        self.settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
        self.settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, True)
        self.settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)
        self.settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, True)
        page = WithConsole()
        self.web.setPage(page)

        #Unlikely to matter but prefer to be waiting for callback then try to catch
        # it in time.
        self.web.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoad)

        self.web.load(QUrl("index.html"))
        self.web.show()

    def onLoad(self):
        global frame
        #This is the body of a web browser tab
        self.myPage = self.web.page()
        self.myPage.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
        self.myFrame = self.myPage.mainFrame()
        self.myFrame.evaluateJavaScript(' document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="work fine inside onLoad";')
        frame=self.myFrame




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    global frame

    myWebApp=HTMLApplication()
    myWebApp.show();
    d=testQthread()
    d.start()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The pb is just that the gui can be called only by the same thread. We must use signal slots stuff.
the good implementation should be:

```
import sys
import time
import PyQt4
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPalette, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsProxyWidget, QGraphicsView, QPainter
from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebSettings
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.setObjectName(name)

    def run(self):
        print "RUN", QThread.currentThread().objectName(), QApplication.instance().thread().objectName()
        self.exec_()
        print "RUN DONE", QThread.currentThread().objectName()

class Producer(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Producer, self).__init__(parent)

    def Start(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print "Producer",i,QThread.currentThread().objectName()
            self.emit(SIGNAL("jseval"),'document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="yes I cans";')
            time.sleep(2)
        time.sleep(1)
        qApp.quit()

class Browser(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Browser, self).__init__(parent)

    def jseval(self, val):
        self.myFrame.evaluateJavaScript(val)


    def show(self):
        self.web = QWebView()
        self.web.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoad)
        self.web.load(QUrl("index.html"))
        self.web.show()

    def onLoad(self):
        self.myPage = self.web.page()
        self.myFrame = self.myPage.mainFrame()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    producer = Producer()
    webBrowser = Browser()
    QThread.currentThread().setObjectName("MAIN")
    producerThread = MyThread("producer")
    producer.moveToThread(producerThread)
    producerThread.started.connect(producer.Start)
    producer.connect(producer, SIGNAL("jseval"), webBrowser.jseval)
    webBrowser.show()
    def aboutToQuit():
        producerThread.quit()
        time.sleep(1)
    qApp.aboutToQuit.connect(aboutToQuit)
    time.sleep(.1)
    producerThread.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```